# How to use SQL DISTINCT to remove duplicates from multiple columns?

Tags: sql, distinct

Let's say I have a table with lots of duplicated values. I want to remove the duplicates for each column *individually*. Using `DISTINCT` removes duplicate combinations of columns so other columns still contain duplicated values.

Original table is:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3    
-----+------+------
 a1  | b1   | c1    
 a1  | b2   | c1
 a2  | b1   | NULL
 a2  | b2   | c1    
 a3  | b1   | c1
 a3  | NULL | NULL
```

My desire result is:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3    
-----+------+------
 a1  | b1   | c1    
 a2  | b2   | NULL    
 a3  | NULL | NULL
```

I can get this result by several query separately:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1 
FROM TABLE

SELECT DISTINCT Col2 
FROM TABLE

SELECT DISTINCT Col3 
FROM TABLE
```

But how can I do it in a singe query and return result in one result set?

Thanks

Comment: `DISTINCT` removes duplicate **rows**, not column values.

Comment: Please post what your input looks like...

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: I've updated the question by adding original table. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a `group by`...

```
;WITH c1 AS (
    SELECT col1
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS [r]
      FROM #foo
     WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY col1
)
, c2 AS (
    SELECT col2
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2) as [r]
      FROM #foo
     WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY col2
)
, c3 AS (
    SELECT col3
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col3) as [r]
      FROM #foo
     WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY col3
)
select c1.col1
     , c2.col2
     , c3.col3
  from c1 LEFT join c2
        on c1.r = c2.r
       left join c3
        on c1.r = c3.r
 ORDER BY c1.r ASC;
```

I wasn't quite sure from the problem description what you wanted. I crafted this based on the ideal-output provided.

Here is the sample data set I used.

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (
    col1 char(2)
  , col2 char(2)
  , col3 char(2)
);

INSERT INTO #foo (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES ('a1', 'b2', null)
     , ('a1', 'b1', 'c1')
     , ('a2', Null, 'c1')
     , ('a2', 'b1', null)
     , ('a3', null, 'c1')
GO
```

Here is the dataset and output from the query:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: You assumed it was MS SQL server. Even if it was MS SQL, what happens when col1 has less distinct values then col2 or col3? (But it is not me who downvoted)

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I didn't assume, but since the requester didn't specify, I bang'ed out an example with SQL Server, but you can translate this to Oracle or MySQL (they support CTEs). This is a total garbage query, but the request is a little hokey. While garbage, it works for the use-case the user provided, no? Agree on your second point; whoever runs this needs to know what columns have the most data sets. If you want to craft a batch to figure that out, have at it. The user's question about " singe query and return result in one result set" was answered.

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly what I want. but my original table is too big and this solution needs several query to run so the performance is low. do you have any other simple workaround to prevent multiple select on the table? Thanks

Comment: I think you're screwed on performance since you're scanning each column one at a time. I don't know a ton about your situation (data size, uniqueness of rows, available temp space, indexes, etc.) A shot in the dark idea. Pull unique rows from the table into a temp/session table then run the query on the temp/session table. If you have 2-mil records of which 300k are unique, you can then run this query against the smaller unique set. Not sure if the net-net time will make the complexity worth while.

Answer (score -1):

You can `UNION` those three queries together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1 FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Col2 FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Col3 FROM TABLE
```

This requires that all three fields be of the same type (can't mix numbers and strings and dates).

This smells of bad design though. If you find yourself unioning these often then perhaps change your table to look like the UNION'd results.